# Flutter Image Asset cannot be shown ( image in class model )

Tags: flutter, rethrow, image-flutter

I've made class model of places, and I want to show the logo of each place, I add the image location folder in class named place_model.dart and this is the code for place_model.dart :

```
class Place{


final String imageUrl;
  final String mall;
  final String city;

  Place({required this.imageUrl, required this.mall, required this.city});

}

final places = [
  Place(
    imageUrl : 'assets/pvj.png',
    mall : 'Paris Van Java',
    city:'Bandung',
  ),
  Place(
    imageUrl : '',
    mall : 'Festival City Link',
    city:'Bandung',
  ),
  Place(
    imageUrl : '',
    mall : 'Istana Plaza',
    city:'Bandung',
  ),
];
```

but the image didn't show up, I've made another code like this ( file place_screen.dart ) :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:smartparking/model/place_model.dart';

class PlaceScreen extends StatefulWidget{
  

  @override 
  _PlaceScreenState createState() => _PlaceScreenState();
}

class _PlaceScreenState extends State<PlaceScreen>{

  Column _buildMallPlaces(){
    List<Widget> mallPlaces =[];
    places.forEach((place){
      mallPlaces.add(
        Container(
          height: 80.0,
          child: Center(  
            child: ListTile(  
              leading: ConstrainedBox(  
                constraints: BoxConstraints(  
                  minWidth: 20,
                  minHeight: 20,
                  maxWidth: 30,
                  maxHeight: 30,
                ),
                child: Image(image: AssetImage(place.imageUrl)),
              ),
              title: Text(
                place.mall,
                style: TextStyle(  
                  fontSize: 18.0,
                  fontWeight : FontWeight.w600,
                ),
              ),
              subtitle: Text(
                '${place.city}',
                style: TextStyle(  
                  fontSize: 16.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                ),
              ),
              
          ))));
    });

    return Column(children: mallPlaces);
  }
  @override 
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView( 
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25, vertical: 50),
        children:<Widget>[
          
        
        SizedBox(height: 10.0),
        Text('Select Mall',
        style: TextStyle(  
          fontSize: 24,  
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,  
        ),),
        SizedBox(height: 20,),_buildMallPlaces()

      ]));
  }
}
```

in pubspec.yaml : ( I've already used tab button not space between "-"  and "assets/.." )

```
uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - assets/
    - assets/icons/
    - assets/frame.png
    - assets/pvj.png
```

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite assets and `flutter pub get`

```
flutter:

  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - assets/icons/
  fonts:
    - family: Inter
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/Inter-Regular.ttf
```

Answer (score 0):

try close ide & clear cache in app and re run .

Answer (score 0):

`uses-material-design` and `assets` must be the same depth.

```
flutter:

  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - assets/
```

Answer (score 0):

Better don't define each and every image in the pubspec.yaml isntead just paste this it will work.
1)

```
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
     - assets/
```

2. 

And make sure you have images in the assets folder and if this still doesn't work try to replace

```
child: Image(image: AssetImage(place.imageUrl)),
```

with

```
child: AssetImage("Imahe.png"),
```

3. Invalidate Cache and Restart and run the project !!

Answer (score 0):

This way is working, the changes are based on Flutter 3.

- I have the put the image in `images` folder that I created in root folder.
- I put condition if the place's imageUrl is empty or not.
- Other language syntax and suggestions from Flutter.

```dart
class PlaceScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PlaceScreenState createState() => _PlaceScreenState();
}

class _PlaceScreenState extends State<PlaceScreen> {
  Column _buildMallPlaces() {
    List<Widget> mallPlaces = [];
    for (var place in places) {
      mallPlaces.add(SizedBox(
          height: 80.0,
          child: Center(
              child: ListTile(
            leading: place.imageUrl.isEmpty
                ? null
                : ConstrainedBox(
                    constraints: const BoxConstraints(
                      minWidth: 20,
                      minHeight: 20,
                      maxWidth: 30,
                      maxHeight: 30,
                    ),
                    child: Image(image: AssetImage(place.imageUrl)),
                  ),
            title: Text(
              place.mall,
              style: const TextStyle(
                fontSize: 18.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
              ),
            ),
            subtitle: Text(
              place.city,
              style: const TextStyle(
                fontSize: 16.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
              ),
            ),
          ))));
    }

    return Column(children: mallPlaces);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: ListView(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25, vertical: 50),
            children: <Widget>[
          const SizedBox(height: 10.0),
          const Text(
            'Select Mall',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 24,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
          _buildMallPlaces()
        ]));
  }
}
```

[image]